# Counterweight of Crankshaft

Tags: mechanical-engineering, applied-mechanics

I want to know the function of counterweights on crankshaft. I heard it is to able the piston to go back up, to repeat the explosion stroke. But doesnt the piston on one cylinder goes back up because the piston in other cylinder is pushed down? This makes the first cylinder go down and up.

Comment: It is the flywheel that stores the energy required to keep the engine turning between power strokes. The counterweights alone are not nearly enough.

Comment: ... Although my father tells the story of when working in a garage long ago, they assembled a car that had a large inline 8-cylinder engine (power stroke for every quarter turn of the crankshaft) without its flywheel and it ran just fine. This configuration is rare today, and back then, engine components were generally much heavier than they really needed to be. I don't know if you could do the same thing with a modern lightweight 8-cylinder engine.

Comment: I think all engines would run without flywheels. But you would have issues with the speed irregularity of the crankshaft and difficulties during clutching.

Answer (score 3):

The counterweighs have two main functions.

1. Reduce the bending load on the crankhsaft. Imagine a 4 cylinder engine with a flat plane crankshaft. The first cylinder is at the top dead center (TDC), the second is at the bottom dead center (BDC). The conrod and the piston of the first cylinder "pulls" the crankshaft up, the second down, while it is fixed at the main bearings. The crankshaft will be deformed at the main bearings, which means a lot of stress at the fillets next to the bearings, and has a negative effect on the lifetime of the bearing shells.
   If you add counterweights to the crankshaft at each cylinder, and adjust the size of these carefully, they will pull the crankshaft with the same force as the conrod and piston, but in the opposite direction, and the crankshaft will have no bending loads
2. In most engines the majority of the forces is countered internally (eg. a 4 cylinder engine has two pistons moving up, 2 moving down, so the engine itself will remain in place). But in some cases, like in a single cylinder engine, or in some 3 cylinder engines the internal forces are not in balance. For these engines you need additional counterweights, so the engine will not shake when the cranktrain is rotating.

In reality it is slightly more complicated, as you will have forces with rotating and alternating directions. You adjust the counterweight size to cancel only a certain amount of the mass forces of the conrod (the "rotating mass"), and not the piston. By how much is a compromise between costs, quality, weight, speed and size.

Also, the forces in the crank mechanism are not exactly sinusoid (inherent from the finite length of the conrod). With counterweights on the crankshaft you can influence the balance only in the first order. For higher frequencies you need additional measures, like extra balancer shafts in the crankcase or in the oilpan. They rotate with twice the speed as the crankshaft, cancelling the second order forces.